# SwaggerHub editor showing extra array brackets at the very end and beginning of the example?

Tags: arrays, syntax, yaml, swagger, swagger-editor

The editor on editor.swagger.io renders the below yaml to a json response that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
      ...
    }
]
```

There is an extra set of array brackets surrounding the response, which I feel may confuse my front end team. Is this normal, or what am I doing wrong with this syntax? Sorry if bad question, still learning yaml.

Yaml:

```
/getFoo:
  get:
    tags:
    - Foo
    summary: Finds foo
    description: Get essential data specifically regarding the bar
   operationId: getFooBar
    produces:
    - application/json
    parameters:
    - name: "foo"
    in: "path"
    description: Identifier used to retrieve foo bar. 
    required: true
    type: "string"
    responses:
    200:
      description: successful foo
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/FooBar'
    400:
      description: No foo found
    500: 
      description: Internal server error.
```

This is what the definition for FooBar is:

```
FooBar:
  type: object
  properties:
    foo: 
      type: string
      example: "123"
  bar:
    type: object
    example: 
      fb: $0.0
      fb1: $0.0
  baz:
    type: array
    items:
      type: object
      properties: 
        1: 
          type: string
          example: 1
        2: 
          type: string
          example: 2
```

Comment: Is the response supposed to be an object or an array of objects? Currently the response is defined as `type: array`, that's why you get an array example `[ ... ]`.

Comment: @Helen I missed that in the responses section! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see an array example because response is defined as array:

```yaml
    responses:
      200:
        description: successful foo
        schema:
          type: array   # <-----
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/FooBar'
```

If the response is supposed to be a single object, change this to:

```yaml
    responses:
      200:
        description: successful foo
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/FooBar'
```